# numpy arange for floating point start & stop

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, floating-point

I want numpy to create a full list, given the parameters start, stop and increment, but ran into some troubles:

```
In[2]: import numpy as np
In[3]: np.arange(2.0, 2.4, 0.2)
Out[3]: array([ 2. ,  2.2])

In[4]: np.arange(2.0, 2.6, 0.2)
Out[4]: array([ 2. ,  2.2,  2.4,  2.6])

In[5]: np.arange(2.0, 2.8, 0.2)
Out[5]: array([ 2. ,  2.2,  2.4,  2.6])
```

What I actually want is:

```
array([ 2. ,  2.2,  2.4])
```

Now, I've learned that I should avoid the floating point data type if it comes down to fixed values. I know it would be better to multiply start/stop/increment by 100, but the problem is that I cannot tell, how many decimals the user is going to supply. Is there any way I can still do that with Float or is there a better way to solve this?

Edit: 
It works now with the obvious solution of adding 0.0000001 to the end-value. But this looks horrible in my code...I'd hope to fix this nicely somehow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you specify which values the user is supposed to enter? For that kind of generation, I think [`linspace`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html#numpy.linspace) could be better as it includes the `end` parameter

EDIT: if the user enters `start`, `end`, and `increment`, just use `linspace` with `num = int((end-start)/increment+1)` if the exact value of the increment is not critical.

EDIT2:
adapt `1e-4` to the relative error you deem acceptable (you can even add it as a user-defined variable).

```
eps = 1e-4*(stop-start)
num = int((stop-start)/(incr-eps)+1)
np.linspace(start, stop,num)
```

Comment: I didn't even know that "linspace" existed and tried to use it. The idea is great, but I run into the same problem:

myList = [2.0, 2.4, 0.2] ; num = int((myList[1] - myList[0]) / myList[2]) ; 

this returns num = 1, probably because the result of 2.4 - 2.0 is handled as 0.39999

Comment: Ok, then you can use the a hack (see edited post). Adapt `1e-4` to the relative error you deem acceptable. You can even add it as a user variable.

Comment: Yep, this works. Nice way to make sure my added value is not interfering with the steps I wish to create. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this might seem a little longer but if you are keen on using np.arange this is  how I worked it out:

```
decimal_places = decimal.Decimal(str(STEP)).as_tuple().exponent
power_10_multiplier = 10**-decimal_places

MIN = int(MIN*power_10_multiplier)
MAX = int(MAX*power_10_multiplier)
STEP = int(STEP*power_10_multiplier)

arr = np.arange(MIN, MAX + STEP, step=STEP)/power_10_multiplier
```