# Creating a sequence of regularly spaced numbers

Tags: python, numpy

I create a sequence of regularly spaced numbers that naively could be taken defined with this simple code:

```
l=6          # Number of elements
h=1          # Spatial regular interval
v=[-h/2]     # First element
for i in range(l,start=1):
    v.append(v[-1]+h)
```

I'm using `np.arange` for that, as in:

```
np.arange(-h/2, h*(l-.5), h)
```

but documentation says that `np.linspace` should be used instead because I'm not using intergers.

```
np.linspace(-h/2, h*(l-.5), l, endpoint=False)
```

Is this approach fail proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.arange` works by adding `step` to `start` and comparing if the result is `>= stop` in which case it will not generate this last value (endpoint), otherwise repeat the operation.

The problem is that floating point numbers can never be compared equal, because of the way they are represented in memory. Take this example for instance:

```
>>> 0.5 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 < 0.8
True
```

That behaviour of floating point numbers could cause a `step=0.1` to be added to the previous generated value of `np.arange` of `0.7` and be less than the `stop=0.8`. This is why sometimes arange seems to return endpoint. It's not really returning endpoint, it's returning a number close to endpoint like `0.7999999999999999` which gets rounded up by the method thats returning the string representation of the floating point number.

This is not the case with `np.linspace` when you have a fixed number of steps, because you wont be comparing floating point numbers but rather calculating the value of a set number of steps. So answering your question, yes it is safe to use `np.linspace` the way you've done. Check this [github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5808) thread for more information.

Note also that I've said you should have a fixed number of steps. If you are trying to calculate the number of steps based on `start` and `stop` you would run into similar problems as you can see on this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36337789/numpy-arange-for-floating-point-start-stop).